# Random coin toss guessing probabilty

Tags: probability

If I guess the outcome of a series of coin tosses by alternating between heads and tails, what are the odds of me getting 7 wrong guesses in a row? Once every _______ coin tosses?

Comment: As you are new to the site:  people here tend not to respond well to questions, like this, that look like homework and which show no effort at all.  What have you tried?  Can you answer the question for one wrong guess?  Two wrong guesses in a row?  Three?  A pattern should emerge.

Comment: Hey Lulu. Thanks for the response. I have no idea how to tackle this. It's out of personal interest for binary options trading online (a new strategy I am thinking of). So no, it's not homework. I'm 35 years old :)

Comment: So, answer my questions.  What is the probability of getting two wrong questions in a row?  In that case you can easily list all the possibilities and simply count.  Same for three wrong guesses in a row.  That should suggest a pattern.

Answer (score 5):

Hints:

- What is the odd of you making one wrong guess ?
- Is you guessed right one time, do you have better odds of guessing right the next time ? Are all guesses independant ?
- If your first guess was wrong what is the odd of your second guess to be wrong as well ?
- Then, can you conclude about the odds of you making two wrong guesses in a row ?
- Can you generalize from here to find the odds of you making three wrong guesses in a row ? seven wrong guesses in a row ? n wrong guesses in a row ?

Btw, the presentation of the answer: "Once every _______ coin tosses?" is a bit misleading. It should rather be "Once every _______ series of 7 coin tosses"

Comment: Damn people. Was just looking for some help and I'm not into statistics. On my next google search, I'll just exclude the "pretentious math nerd community"... You guys are too much... Hahaha

Comment: The "pretentious math nerd community" spent more time trying to help you than you spent yourself either for asking the question or for trying to follow our leads.